# How to get user claims in postman from from Azure active directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a few users added to my Azure AD account, I would like to get the information on these users by calling an Azure API from Postman in the form of claims. I tried calling the following URL with the parameters as :

https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantId/oauth2/token

Body:
grant_type : client_credentials,
client_id : client id,
client secret : client secret

I receive the access_token in the encoded format in the response, When I decode it on https://jwt.io/ I see the decoded data, but there's no user information in the access_token.

I would like to get the user information in the form of claims in the response.

What approach would I need to take on this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get user information in the token, you should change the grant_type to password. And provide the username and password in the body.

[image]

Here is the user screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, and what should be there in the "resource" field?

Comment: It depends on you, if you want to call azure rest api, you should use https://management.azure.com/. If you want to call graph api, you should use https://graph.microsoft.com

Comment: @MukkuP azure rest api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/  Microsoft graph rest api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: The username and password should be that has been added to AD account, right ?

Comment: An alternative way (though harder) is to configure OAuth authorization in Postman with the right values so it gives you the login popup. That'll work even if the user has MFA or is federated, in which the password flow won't work.

Comment: @ the username and password are the user credential which you add to your ad tennant. You can check it in the answer. I have updated it.

Comment: @MukkuP Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: @MukkuP can you past your request with params in your question?

Comment: @MukkuP thanks. Did you add a user like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory? After that, you need to login in azure portal with this new account to change the password. Make sure you have the correct username and password.

Comment: @MukkuP Have you tried the other users which user type is member?

Comment: I am a member in AD but my username is from different AD instance (which is home  directory of my user). I think that's why it's showing as "Invalid User name ......"

Comment: Yes, you are right. You need to use the user like user@{your current ad tenantname}

Comment: @MukkuP If my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thank you. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Thank you for your help, How can I also get the roles for the user ?

Comment: @MukkuP You can refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work to accept an answer.

Comment: @MukkuP If you want to get the roles for the user, you need to get it from the id_token. If you want to know the detailed steps, you can post a new question, then I can answer you in details. Here is the sample code for your reference. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims

Comment: I have posted a new question for roles, plz check